Workbench SOQL - Aggregate Relationships not supported in Bulk Query
I am receiving error for the SOQL query I ran in Workbench for Bulk CSV:
Failed: InvalidBatch : Failed to process query: FUNCTIONALITY_NOT_ENABLED: Aggregate Relationships not supported in Bulk Query
Any suggestions how I can access the full data set?

As per doc bulk API query doesn’t support relationship fields.

Any workaround?

Can you please share your SOQL for this?

As per this documentation, Bulk API doesn’t support queries with any of the following:

GROUP BY, OFFSET, or TYPEOF clauses
Aggregate functions such as COUNT()
Date functions in GROUP BY clauses (date functions in WHERE clauses are supported)
Compound address fields or compound geolocations fields

